# Skipped a lot of frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread

Tags: android, multithreading

i'm new in the word of game development.. I stared a few day ago a tutorial in Android Studio. After this tutorial I tried to make my app. Why when I set a background on Relativelayout the app crash? It says "Skipped 823 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread"
I tried to run the app without the background. It works perfectly! :(
The background it's a 1920X1080 png file. I tried also with jpg file and another layout but the result was the same. 
Thank you guys for your help!!

Comment: `The application may be doing too much work on its main thread` already says a lot. But loading a 1920x1080 bitmap is really a risky business, if not using a gear such as the Universal Image Loader. Also try increasing your heap size.

Comment: Some code would definitely help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the image in the folder:

```
/res/drawable-nodpi/
```

Hope this helps!

---

**FYI:** If you put the picture in any dpi-folders it will be resampled by their density and this costs lot of computing-time. If you put your image in the nodpi-folder the image simply won't be resampled.

Comment: Thank you man.. Now it's ok. But can you explain me what is going on?

Comment: I am glad to hear i could help you Stanciu. Actually if you put the picture in any dpi-folders they will be resampled by their density and this costs lot of computing. If you put your image in the nodpi-folder the image won't be resampled.
I would be happy if you could accept my answer, so anybody else with the same error might see the correct solution!

Comment: Thank you a lot. But if I put the images in the nodpi-folder will it display the picture different on different devices?

Comment: Since different devices have different screen densities, yes. But there is another way you can scale it by yourself using: "BitmapFactory.decodeResource()"
But first try if it is needed at all. Hope i could help!